# Setting Breakpoints on ARM Thumb Instructions in GDB

Tags: debugging, arm, gdb, qemu, thumb

I'm practicing reversing a stripped arm binary (that I wrote) and found that when I set a breakpoint at say `0x010451`, and run the program, gdb spins forever until I hit ctrl+c.  When I do, the current pc is at the address, but I can't continue the program.

When I set the breakpoint to `0x010450`, gdb hits the breakpoint fine, but the instructions are being decoded as non-thumb instructions.

Is this expected?  A bug?  I will try to upload examples later today.

Version info (under qemu usermode emulation):

```
debian@debian-arm:~/lab$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (Debian 8.2.1-2+b3) 8.2.1
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
debian@debian-arm:~/lab$ uname -a
Linux debian-arm 4.19.0-10-armmp-lpae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24) armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Strangely, setting `set arm fallback-mode thumb` worked when `set arm fallback-mode auto` didn't. It now stops on the proper thumb instruction when setting the breakpoint to the odd address instead of spinning until I hit ctrl+c

Comment: note the address of the label is the even number, the odd bit is consumed by the instruction (bx lr, pop {pc}, etc) and the pc only contains the even address...what gdb is expecting, dont know.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  I can't reproduce breaking on the odd numbered address like I mentioned before.  `set arm fallback-mode thumb` works well enough for me now though.  I'm not sure why the T bit is not being set in the register when I have fallback-mode set to auto though...